Import as Table imports 51d60 as 5.1*10^61
I have a data for which the first column has data such as 51d60, 52d60 and so on. When I do Import["filename.txt","Table"], the first column imports as 5.1*10^(61) instead. What is the best way to import such data?

It is probably so obvious to you that you didn't even think to mention it, what do you want  51d60 to be turned into inside Mathematica?

Are you sure that letter d is not an e ?

Mathematica interprets 51d60 as 51 * 10^60 = 5.1 * 10 * 10^60 = 5.1 * 10^61. Therefore 5.1*10^(61) is a correct, expected result. Do you want to import 51d60 not as a number but as a string ? If so, try Import["filename.txt", "Data"].

This behaviour is explained in the third example under Possible Issues in the documentation for CSV: Entries of the format "nnnDnnn" or "nnnEnnn" are interpreted as numbers with scientific notation. Use the "Numeric" -> False option to override this interpretation.
